# Can we use static methods in JMX bean?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I have Constants class in my web application.

I want to monitor `Constants` class using `Jconsole`.

I have `@ManagedResource` used  annotation for Constants class and `@ManagedAttribute`for setter method.

If I will use `@ManagedAttribute` for static method then it will not displayed in `Jconsole` and for non-static method it works fine.

Can you please provide explanation why it was not working with static method?

Following is my Constants class.

```
@ManagedResource(
        objectName  = "Sample:name=ActivityQueueUtil",
        description = "Allows modifying all settings."
)
public class ActivityQueueUtil {

    private static volatile ActivityQueueUtil instance;

    public static ActivityQueueUtil getInstance() {
        if (instance == null ) {
            synchronized (Constants.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ActivityQueueUtil();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public void initInstance() {
        instance = this;
    }

    private int currentWorkerCount = 0;
    private int currentQueueSize = 0;
    private int currentRetryQueueSize = 0;

    @ManagedAttribute(description = "Current number of worker threads.")
    public static int getCurrentWorkerCount() {
    return currentWorkerCount;
    }

    public void setCurrentWorkerCount(int currentWorkerCount) {
    this.currentWorkerCount = currentWorkerCount;
    }

    @ManagedAttribute(description = "Number of activities in the queue")
    public int getCurrentQueueSize() {
    return currentQueueSize;
    }
}
```

Here it works for `setCurrentWorkerCount,getCurrentQueueSize` but not working for `getCurrentWorkerCount`